# Data Structures: Wikipedia-like Tree

Tags: performance, data-structures, tree, hierarchy, wikipedia

I am currently in the process of developing an ontology, a web hierarchy of categories of *everything* (think persons, places, things). The finished product should be something that allows me to navigate from Technology->Computers->Laptops->USB Ports, but also from Movies->Minority Report->Computers->etc.
I need an efficient data structure to group these. I need a tree-like graph, but a special tree that allows child nodes to have multiple parent nodes. 
In thinking over this, I have realized that Wikipedia is an imperfect model for this. In fact, they have a hierarchy starting [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFundamental_categories) that is essentially exactly what I need. I see that they used a directed graph, but I am wondering what the differences/drawbacks between this directed graph, a directed acyclic graph, and a polytree are. I have tried researching it, but I don't quite understand the differences. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: BTW: Wikipedia categories allow cycles, altough they are not wanted by the community. The german system is a better example for a multitree, rooted at [!Hauptkategorie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:!Hauptkategorie)

Comment: Do you perhaps mean an [ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science))? Otherwise this sounds just like a general directed graph.

Comment: Yes, I do mean an ontology. Thanks for the proper jargon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the articles at Wikipedia give a good overview:

- A [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) is a set of nodes connected by edges which have a direction associated with them.
- A [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG) is a directed graph with no [directed cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Directed_cycle_graph).
- A [polytree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree) (also called directed tree) is a directed graph with exactly one undirected path between any two vertices. In other words, a polytree is a directed graph whose underlying undirected graph is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)), or equivalently, a [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) directed acyclic graph for which there are no undirected cycles either.

So I think you search for a connected directed acyclic graph. Altough the Wikipedia category system allows cycles, they are unwanted.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wasn't quite sure what the Wikipedia meant by "directed", though. Could you please explain what it means for an edge to have a direction? Is it just jargon for parent->child? *sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: No, it is just a general term. A graph of parent-child connections would be directed, yes, but not every directed edge means parent->child (like in a tree).

Comment: "directed" means you can only travel in the "direction" of the edge from the "from node" to the "to node" (not backwards). In an "undirected" graph, you can travel back and forth from node to node on an edge.

Comment: Thanks @Justin, so if I wish to travel upwards from, say, Basketball to Sports, I would need an undirected graph?

Comment: No, in an undirected graph you would not know that it is "up" or "down", just "you can travel". But your directed graph may provide a method "getIncomingEdges(node)" which returns for example "Sports" and "Balls".

Comment: @RMartin If you wanted to travel upwards from Basketball to Sports you  could use an additional directed edge (essentially, a directed edge from Basketball to Sports and one from Sports to Basketball). But if you "always" want to be able to travel in both directions then an undirected graph is the way to go.

Comment: @Justin: No, in an undirected graph you can *not* travel in any directions :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I said that. What I mean is: if you are at node Basketball you can travel from Basketball to _any_ node which has an edge connection to Basketball.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Justin and @Bergi! So with an undirected graph I can travel from Basketball, up to Sports or down to, say, Basketball Players. Always. But with a directed graph, unless I specifically add in a second directed edge, I cannot travel both ways. Is this correct? 
Is a directed graph less/more costly than an undirected graph, efficency-wise?

Comment: @RMartin You got it. An undirect graph is somewhat easier to implement than a directed graph. I think if you have a lot of bi-directional edges between nodes then a directed graph is more space consuming but not really a big deal. From a processor point of view a undirected graph may be a bit faster since the logic is simpler but also not a big deal.

Comment: No, you can travel around on all types of graphs. "directed" means only there is a *direction information* on the edges which says which node is "up" and which is "down" (or parent/child or whatever). That means it needs more storage capacity. The efficiency is implementation-dependent on the tasks you want to do.

Comment: @Bergi So it seems either graph lets me travel up or down, but a directed graph actually stores the information of which node is up and which is down. Kind of like a linked list? And having it directed up and down would be kind of like a doubly linked list? An undirected graph is simpler, lighter. But a directed graph is faster when we need to be going up and down branches frequently. I'm speculating here, is this correct?

Comment: I think what you have defined here is not a *polytree* (also called a *directed tree*) but a *polyforest* (also called a *directed forest*). A *polytree* is a directed graph with **exactly** one undirected path between any two vertices. In other words, a *polytree* is a **connected** directed acyclic graph for which there are no undirected cycles either. For a reference, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225762/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-tree-for-directed-graphs).